# Por que content-type false AJAX - JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou enviando arquivos via AJAX com Jquery, usando o `FormData()`, e dai surgiu uma dúvida, porquê isso trabalha:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"action/receipt.php",
  method:"POST",
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  data: form,
  success:function(data){

  }

});
```

e isso não?

```
$.ajax({
  url:"action/receipt.php",
  method:"POST",
  processData: false,
  data: form,
  success:function(data){

  }

});
```

Digo, da primeira forma a variável `$_FILES` imprime os valores esperados, na segunda, ela está vazia.

Por qual razão não preencher o content-type pode ocasionar em `$_FILES` vazio? Seria por causa de o padrão ser em um formato de envio diferente de `multipart/form-data`, ou eu estou viajando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você usa o `contentType` com o valor `false`, você está forcando o jQuery a não passar o valor padrão para o `contentType` da requisição. O padrão, como citado anteriormente, é o `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Provavelmente, quando se faz com no exemplo abaixo, o `jQuery` importará essas informações de contentType diretamente do `form`.

```
var f = new FormData($('#form').get(0));

$.ajax({ data: f, contentType: false, cache: false, processData: false})
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é isso mesmo. Se verificar na requisição efetivamente realizada pelo browser (utilizando as ferramentas de desenvolvimento) vai ver que o `Content-Type` padrão é o `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, cujo processamento do lado do servidor é completamente diferente do `multipart/form-data`.